# Selenium Exception when duplicate elements are present

Tags: exception, selenium-webdriver

Which exception will be thrown by selenium when three elements are present with the same id and it tries to click on one of them?

Comment: Why id would be same? Id is a thing which is unique. and if there's a duplicate ids make custom exception.

Comment: sometimes developers give the same id to multiple elements. In that case what will happen?

Comment: Its developer fault element id should be unique in a page

Comment: You can make custom exception when multiple elements get found.

Comment: Create or find a page and try it yourself. Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium won't throw any exception.  it will locate the very first element and perform the action on that only

Comment: happy to here :) If the answer is helpful please `accept` it